# How to change selected row background color in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to set background color on list view item on when a click is done. 
A custom adapter is used for list view in Android

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/selectablelistview-make-selection-work/ It should help you achieve.

Comment: when i am changing selected value color not removing from there.

Answer (score 5):

Save position of clicked item and check it from getView()'s position of adapter. if both are same then set any background color or resources as

```
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
      or    
   convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

where convertView is your inflated layout of adapter.

Comment: Thanks but . color not remove when changing selected value.

Comment: Write above code in if else condition. that is if both are same then your selected color and else your default color. it might be help you.

Comment: and invalidate listview on Item click. as       lstView.invalidateViews();

Answer (score 0):

myDrawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/YOUR_COLOR_HERE" />
    <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/YOUR_COLOR_HERE" />
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/YOUR_COLOR_HERE" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/YOUR_COLOR_HERE" /> 
</selector>
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/myDrawable">
        <!-- other views in layout-->
    </LinearLayout>
```

Or add this attribute to you listview

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:state_activated="true">
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#333333" />
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" />
  </shape></item>
<item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#222222" />
    </shape></item>
```